# How to cross-compile Coreutils or other GNU projects with clang/LLVM?

Tags: clang, cross-compiling, gnu-coreutils

I have a tough need to compile Coreutils with llvm for other arch: arm/aarch64/mips/mips32/ppc/ppc32...

Since I install all the gcc-cross tools like `mips-linux-gnu`, `powerpc64-linux-gnu` and if I have a simple C program like that test.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("hello!");
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile it to the arch, i.e.

```
clang --target=mips64-linux-gnuabi64 test.c -o test-mips64
➜  tests file test-mips64 
test-mips64: ELF 64-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS64 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld.so.1, BuildID[sha1]=7b33d55a0d08e6cd18d966341590dc351e346a78, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

I try to the same way for compile Coreutils that try to set

```
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
CFLAGS = "--target=mips64-linux-gnuabi64"
./configure --host=mips64-linux-gnuabi64
```

Howerver, every time got errors in configure or make...

How should I set the configure? Can I easily compile Coreuntils with llvm for other archs?

Comment: There are a ton of things you need to get right when it comes to cross compiling. We need more information to help you out. At least a description of what you tried and the errors you ran into.

Comment: Also which system are you working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to get the command-line options right for cross-compiling. I got it to work with the commands below, assuming you're working on a Debian-based system (like Debian or Ubuntu). Here are the steps.

1. Install `gcc-mips64-linux-gnuabi64` and `gcc-powerpc64-linux-gnu`.
2. Choose the correct arguments for `CFLAGS`

   - `-B/usr/mips64-linux-gnuabi64/bin/` to indicate we want to use the linker `ld` within that directory. Do the same for powerpc.
   - `--target=mips64-linux-gnuabi64` to indicate what our target for compilation is. Do the same for powerpc.
   - `-I/usr/mips64-linux-gnuabi64/include` to include header files. Do the same for powerpc.
3. Use `./configure --host=mips64-linux-gnuabi` to configure for mips64 and `./configure --host=powerpc64-linux-gnueabi` to configure for powerpc64.

Here are the commands to compile for mips64:

```
make clean
CFLAGS="-B/usr/mips64-linux-gnuabi64/bin/ --target=mips64-linux-gnuabi64 -I/usr/mips64-linux-gnuabi64/include" \
    ./configure --host=mips64-linux-gnuabi
make
```

And the commands to compile for powerpc64:

```
make clean
CFLAGS="-B/usr/powerpc64-linux-gnu/bin/ --target=powerpc64-linux-gnueabi -I/usr/powerpc64-linux-gnu/include" \
    ./configure --host=powerpc64-linux-gnueabi
make
```

Here is the output of `file ./src/ls` to demonstrate that it is a powerpc64 executable:

```
$ file ./src/ls
./src/ls: ELF 64-bit MSB executable, 64-bit PowerPC or cisco 7500, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=97fe33981ca0112160f44a6fb678d6dc1b462114, not stripped
```

---

Below is a Dockerfile that can be used to reproducibly cross-compile coreutils for mips64 and powerpc64.

```
# Cross-compile GNU coreutils for mips64 and powerpc64 using clang.
# With help from https://medium.com/@wolfv/cross-compiling-arm-on-travis-using-clang-and-qemu-2b9702d7c6f3

FROM debian:buster

# Install compile-time dependencies.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --yes \
        clang \
        curl \
        gcc-mips64-linux-gnuabi64 \
        gcc-powerpc64-linux-gnu \
        make \
        perl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Download source code for release.
WORKDIR /tmp/coreutils
RUN curl -fsSL https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.32.tar.xz \
    | tar xJ --strip-components 1

# Compile and install for mips64.
RUN CFLAGS="-B/usr/mips64-linux-gnuabi64/bin/ --target=mips64-linux-gnuabi64 -I/usr/mips64-linux-gnuabi64/include" \
        ./configure --host=mips64-linux-gnuabi --prefix=/opt/coreutils-mips \
    && make \
    && make install

# Compile and install for powerpc64.
RUN make clean \
    && CFLAGS="-B/usr/powerpc64-linux-gnu/bin/ --target=powerpc64-linux-gnueabi -I/usr/powerpc64-linux-gnu/include" \
        ./configure --host=powerpc64-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/opt/coreutils-powerpc64 \
    && make \
    && make install

# Keep only the compiled programs from the previous stage.
FROM debian:buster
COPY --from=0 /opt /opt
```

Answer (score 0):

I am current working on a simple build tool in Python that maybe help you.
Unfortunately, still at moment, lacks clang implementation, but works fine with GCC and MSVC.
Basically the thing mix Json parameters files to generate command line building.

[CppMagic](https://github.com/Clecius/CppMagic)